# sonar-java-plugin-2.1.jar related plugins getting downloaded everytime on sonar server restart

Tags: sonarqube

We are currently using sonar 4.3.3 release.Here we had uninstalled 
**sonar-java-plugin-2.1.jar** and had moved to ***sonar-java-plugin-2.5.1.jar***
Parallely we had removed the other related plugins also i.e :

1. sonar-surefire-plugin-2.1.jar
2. sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.1.jar
3. sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.1.jar
4. sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.1.jar

Now the problem we are facing is after our quarterly maintenance activity is over and sonar-server restart happens, Sonarqube update-center is downloading the uninstalled old plugins on restart.

List of such plugins:

1. sonar-surefire-plugin-2.1.jar
2. sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.1.jar
3. sonar-squid-java-plugin-2.1.jar
4. sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.1.jar

This is causing the sonarqube auto restart to fail with below-given error

```
2017.01.29 20:32:43 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformServletContextListener]  Fail to start server
org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.IncompatiblePluginVersionException: The plugins 'jacoco' and 'java' must have exactly the same version as they belong to the same group.
```

Please guide if there is any way to disable this behaviour.
Have checked the extensions/downloads/ folder also and no jars were present there.

Comment: You're not likely to get a lot of help here; that SQ version is quite old. Consider upgrading to the LTS version, 5.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jars were present in lib/bundled-plugins folder.Removing from there solved my purpose.